# asp.net core razor pages: get body of ajax call in controller function

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor

Say i have this ajax to the server:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Jobs/Sprachen/?handler=RandomNumber",
                data: JSON.stringify({ Min: testvariable, Max: "no" }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                //nothing for now
            });
```

... and I have this function:

```
public IActionResult OnPostRandomNumber([FromBody]string input)
        {
            // called from ajax (no page reload) 
            return new JsonResult("input: "+input);
        }
```

Why is there always "null" on my input variable?

I wouldve expected a json.

The function it self fires fine and the result is returned and written to the console, but never with anything on the variable

Comment: If you are passing two variables to a controller function, you need to have two params in the controller function that have the same names as the ones passed in the ajax call. for example here you'd have `Max` and `Min`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net Core achieve model binding via property's name. Here your parameter can't match to the data you send in ajax. You can create a model contains `Max` and `Min` property, then use this model as parameter.

```
public class Input
    {
        //I'm not sure what's the type of Max property, I use string to test.
        public string? Max { get; set; }
        public string Min { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the backend

```
public IActionResult OnPostRandomNumber([FromBody]Input model)
        {
            // called from ajax (no page reload) 
            return new JsonResult(model);
        }
```

Now the parameter can receive data successfully

[image]